# What does 'you're not worth staying' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

In the song 'Sound of Walking Away' by Illenium, comes this verse:

> Now, don't come find me 
>   I won't be here waiting 
>   I so can do it alone 
>   You're not worth staying

My question is staying where?

Does it mean the same as

You're not worth staying with?

Comment: She's saying, “I would stay with (or near) you if I had a good reason to stay, but you are not a good enough reason.”

Answer (score 1):

She’s not staying “here”, waiting for him.

Without knowing the full lyrics (and maybe even if I did), I’m not sure whether “here” is a physical location or a metaphor for their relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think she is saying that he doesn't deserve she stays there waiting for her. Maybe because he leaved and left her alone when she needed him, maybe because he hurted her so many times before, etc.

Comment: I don't usually correct people's English unless they've asked; but this is a site for English Learners. The past of _leave_ is _left_, and the past of _hurt_ is _hurt_.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't good grammar, but modern song lyrics often dispense with the rules of grammar to support a rhythm or rhyme scheme.

Given that the first person of the song is the one who is leaving ("I won't be waiting") I would suggest that the line in question should be "you're not worth staying *for*". In other words, the subject of the song is not a reason for him to stay.